# Spark Hbase connector not working in parallel mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I am trying to use Hortonworks hbase connector for spark 2.0 to work with hbase (https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/v1.1.0-2.0)

With the provided example in the above link,

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName(getClass.toString)
      .getOrCreate()

def withCatalog(cat: String, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    spark
      .read
      .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->cat))
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
      .load()
  }
    val df = withCatalog(cat, spark)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(20, false)
```

**Schema:**

```
val cat =
         s"""{
            |"table":{"namespace":"test", "name":"test_src_data", "tableCoder":"PrimitiveType"},
            |"rowkey":"tfkod_description",
            |"columns":{
            |"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"tfkod_description", "type":"string"},
            |"src_stream_desc":{"cf":"src_data", "col":"src_desc", "type":"string"}
            |}
            |}""".stripMargin
```

After I do  spark2-submit the job runs and print only the schema. Later all the excutors are existing and stuck forever.

**Last Message in log:**

Existing executor 41 has been removed (new total is 1)

But I could successfully work with Hbase in sequential way i.e put or BulkPut but not RDD or DF (with any of hbase connector) way to work in spark.

Is there anything wrong in hbase / spark config due to which spark executor not able to work in parallel ? or something missing in worker nodes ?

**Error Message from Worker:**

```
19/05/13 11:36:44 ERROR ipc.AbstractRpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:766)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:32651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallScanner$SmallScannerCallable.call(ClientSmallScanner.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientSmallScanner$SmallScannerCallable.call(ClientSmallScanner.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: adding master("local[*]") makes it to work in gateway node.

Comment: please add full error log

Comment: @shay__ added executor log. to summarise the spark-submit work in local mode but not in yarn. while i submit in yarn it print error in worker log as GSS error.

Comment: @WilliamR You are running on a kerberized cluster, Need to attain the krbtgt or a keytab from the prinicipal based on the user.

Comment: or include the hbase-site.xml under SPARK_CONF_DIR (/etc/spark/conf) on the host where the spark job is submitted from, by creating a symbolic link towards your main hbase-site.xml (in order to be synchronous with your platform updates).